# Not being able spot the problem in the code in Dijkstra’s Haskell implementation

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, monads, ghc, st-monad

I understand that asking “why my code does not work” is not the best question. However, I am asking as I wish to learn more about using monads in Haskell in an algorithmic context for graph theory problems, and took the following code as a starting point to understand how the ST monad would be used in such an algorithm.

I made progress on some simpler algorithms (quick sort) and progressed to Dijkstra’s algorithm. I was unable to compile the following implementation (written in 2012) of Dijkstra’s algorithm: http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Haskell

The error I get is the following :

```
• Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: MArray (STArray s) e0 m
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        f :: forall (m :: * -> *).
             (MArray (STArray s) e0 m, MArray (STArray s) v m) =>
             Set (a0, v) -> (v, a0) -> m (Set (a0, v))
      In the expression:
        let
          edges = adj_list ! u
          f vertex_queue (v, weight) = do ...
        in foldM f vertex_queue' edges >>= aux
      In a case alternative:
          Just ((dist, u), vertex_queue')
            -> let
                 edges = adj_list ! u
                 f vertex_queue (v, weight) = ...
               in foldM f vertex_queue' edges >>= aux
   |
18 |                 f vertex_queue (v, weight) = do
```

(PS : this is not for a school assignment, this is just self-motivated), I have tried everything I knew in Haskell (including proper indentations) but couldn’t succeed.

Comment: Can you share the program you wrote? Right now we can only see the error.

Comment: As mentioned, I did not write the code myself. I have shared the link to the code in my question. I can also share the code from the link if you say.

Comment: Perhaps you should add `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` as the error suggests, although it is hard to say if this is a problem with not enabling an extension or just that you made a mistake when designing the algorithm.

Comment: what if you add `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` to the top of the file?

Comment: Okay, let me try and I will get back to you!

Comment: Wow, it worked! I knew about the Language extensions, but I was unable to decipher that the "Use FlexibleContexts” was a directive to add the extension. I will keep this in mind for the future. I am so thankful to you Willem, I had been stuck on this for the weekend.

Comment: perhaps "use the `FlexibleContext` extension" would have been a better error message.

Comment: when faced with strange and vague new terms you could try taking a long route and internet-search-engine them. of course at the beginning  every term is vague and new....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the algorithm makes use of the [**`FlexibleContexts`** extension [haskell.org]](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/flexible_contexts.html). Normally only constraints of the form *`C t`*, or *`C (q t1 t2 … tn)`* can be used, with `C` a typeclass and *`q`*, *`t`* and *`ti`* type variables. By enabling the `FlexibleContexts`, the constraints can also make use of type constructors.

The compiler detects that the type constraints use `(MArray (STArray s) e0 m, MArray (STArray s) v m)` as context, so with `STArray` as a type constructor, which is not allowed. The compiler detects this and raises an error that mentions:

> ```
> (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
> ```

The compiler thus gives advise on what might fix the problem, although I agree it is a bit "cryptic".

You thus can enable this with a language pragma in the head of the file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

--- rest of the file ⋮
```